# Combine dictionary entries into new dictionary entry based on similar keys with python

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got the following dictionaries:

```
{'grade': '7', 'current_student_sum': 1559}
{'grade': '8', 'current_student_sum': 1638}
{'grade': 'KF', 'current_student_sum': 1588}
{'grade': 'KA', 'current_student_sum': 1588}
{'grade': 'PA', 'current_student_sum': 366}
{'grade': 'PF', 'current_student_sum': 54}
{'grade': 'PP', 'current_student_sum': 384}
```

I am trying to find the cleanest way to loop through there and sum any grade starting with 'P' (and do the same with 'K')

End result:

I am trying to get the dictionaries to look like this:

```
{'grade': '7', 'current_student_sum': 1559}
{'grade': '8', 'current_student_sum': 1638}
{'grade': 'K', 'current_student_sum': 3176}
{'grade': 'P', 'current_student_sum': 816}
```

An alternative solution would be if it was like this:

```
{
'grade': 'K', 'student_sum': 3176,
'grade': 'P', 'student_sum': 816,
..etc
}
```

I've seen the methods using `Counter` but that is only if the key's are matching across dictionaries.

These don't necessarily *have* to be dictionaries if making them lists or something makes it a little easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
d = [{'grade': '7', 'current_student_sum': 1559}, {'grade': '8', 'current_student_sum': 1638}, {'grade': 'KF', 'current_student_sum': 1588},{'grade': 'KA', 'current_student_sum': 1588}, {'grade': 'PA', 'current_student_sum': 366}, {'grade': 'PF', 'current_student_sum': 54}, {'grade': 'PP', 'current_student_sum': 384}]
new_d = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x['grade'][0]), key=lambda x:x['grade'][0])]
final_grade = [{'grade':a, 'current_student_sum':sum(i['current_student_sum'] for i in b)} for a, b in new_d]
```

Output:

```
[{'grade': '7', 'current_student_sum': 1559}, 
 {'grade': '8', 'current_student_sum': 1638}, 
 {'grade': 'K', 'current_student_sum': 3176}, 
 {'grade': 'P', 'current_student_sum': 804}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
import collections
res = collections.defaultdict(int)
data = [{'grade': '7', 'current_student_sum': 1559},
{'grade': '8', 'current_student_sum': 1638},
{'grade': 'KF', 'current_student_sum': 1588},
{'grade': 'KA', 'current_student_sum': 1588},
{'grade': 'PA', 'current_student_sum': 366},
{'grade': 'PF', 'current_student_sum': 54},
{'grade': 'PP', 'current_student_sum': 384}]

for i in data:
    res[i['grade'][0]] += i["current_student_sum"]

res = [{'grade':k, 'current_student_sum':v}  for k,v in res.items()]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'current_student_sum': 1638, 'grade': '8'},
 {'current_student_sum': 3176, 'grade': 'K'},
 {'current_student_sum': 1559, 'grade': '7'},
 {'current_student_sum': 804, 'grade': 'P'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A vectorised solution is possible with 3rd party Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

L = [{'grade': '7', 'current_student_sum': 1559},
     {'grade': '8', 'current_student_sum': 1638},
     {'grade': 'KF', 'current_student_sum': 1588},
     {'grade': 'KA', 'current_student_sum': 1588},
     {'grade': 'PA', 'current_student_sum': 366},
     {'grade': 'PF', 'current_student_sum': 54},
     {'grade': 'PP', 'current_student_sum': 384}]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)

res = df.groupby(df['grade'].str[0])['current_student_sum'].sum()\
        .reset_index().to_dict('records')

print(res)

[{'current_student_sum': 1559, 'grade': '7'},
 {'current_student_sum': 1638, 'grade': '8'},
 {'current_student_sum': 3176, 'grade': 'K'},
 {'current_student_sum': 804, 'grade': 'P'}]
```